# Asking three related soft questions and related matters

Tags: discussion, advice, soft-question

Hello everyone,

I would like to ask three related soft (CW) questions, but I don't really know how I should do it. The questions are:

1. It seems to me that there's is a great focus on Plane Geometry as a first proof-based course in high-school for 16-17-18 year olds in Western Europe and the United States. Why, if this a correct assertion, is there such a great focus on Plane Geometry as a first proof-based "course" in high-school in my country (Holland) and I believe many others throughout the world? (As opposed to, say, elementary number theory.)
2. Have people ever tried to base such a first course on any other branch of mathematics?
3. If the answer to (2) is "yes", to what extend was the attempt succesfull?

I know the general policy of asking questions on MSE is "one question per post", but I feel these questions are so related that they could fit in one post. How do you feel about this?

Furthermore, I would like to know if there is such a thing as a Math - or Science in general - Discussion website for asking soft-discussiony questions like these. I am talking about something that is at the intersection point of MO, MSE, blogs and a Forum.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: Concerning 1.: I just wanted to point out that there was a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22686/what-is-the-mathematical-point-of-geometric-constructions) whose answers at least partially address what you ask.

Comment: @ Theo Thanks for pointing it out. I couldn't find that question while trying to find out if one of my questions was already asked because I looked at the tag "education" and that question wasn't there at that section. I edited the question so it's more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it'll be a judgment call. I think you could ask 1. and then ask 2. and 3. together. But 1. was already discussed either here or on MO, and I think 2. was as well (depending on exactly what you mean by "high school") although unfortunately I couldn't tell you what keywords to look for.

As for your last question, that's roughly what [PlanetMO](https://mathblogging.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/new-feature-introducing-planetmo/) is for, and you might also want to try your luck with [quora](http://www.quora.com/), although I don't know much about it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Qiaochu. I am now trying to find the relevant questions on either MO or MSE you're referring to. I found this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19957/how-do-you-approach-your-childs-math-education-closed but I don't think that's the question you're thinking of. I also found this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40412/if-you-could-redesign-a-high-school-mathematics-curriculum-from-the-ground-up-wh and this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/what-should-the-high-school-math-curriculum-consist-of . Perhaps you were referring to this question (cont'nd)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64448/interesting-and-accessible-topics-in-graph-theory when you were talking about graph theory?

Comment: By the way, about PlanetMO: it seems to me you can only post something there if you have a blog. Is this impression correct?

Comment: @Max: yes, I think that was the graph theory question I was thinking of. You're right about PlanetMO, but it is very easy to start a WordPress blog. (It is slightly harder to get people to read what you have to say, of course...)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that before you ask a "why"-question you should thoroughly check that you do not have wrong assumptions.

A question about "why" something holds "throughout the world" is highly susceptible to this problem.

Why not start with:

"In [my country/these countries] a first introduction to proofs [at age X] is usually based on plane geometry.

Are there other successful/more successful/unsuccessful examples of introducing students to proofs?"

Comment: You're absolutely right, I agree with you. I meant to give more details and be more specific in the "background" section of the question(s).